# Is there any way to convert from Double to NSNumber and maintain accuracy down to at least 6 decimal places in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, double, nsnumber

I was using a `Get` and `Set` to store a `Double` into Core Data as an `NSNumber`. During this conversion which was something like this.

```
var number {
    get { 
        return coreDataNumber.double
    }
    set {
    coreDataNumber = NSNumber(double: newValue!)
    }
}
```

If the syntax is wrong, that has nothing to do with my question, I'm just not on my Mac right now. I eventually came to the conclusion the only way to maintain accuracy on the conversion was to use a String to store the Double. I am fine with using this method, but for my future knowledge, is there a way to prevent a number like 0.003459 from becoming 0.0034589999999999999999 when you retrieve it? This wasn't the only conversion error I found. Sometimes it would round when I didn't want it to. I understand this probably has something to do with that not all decimal values can be properly portrayed in binary. If there is a way to convert without losing accuracy I would appreciate that knowledge.

Comment: What is the format of the property in Core Data? Likely you should switch to decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accuracy is much higher than 6 decimal digits.

Using your numbers: 
 `0.003459 - 0.0034589999999999999999 = 1e-22`

The problem is the formatting function (or lack thereof).

Comment: You are right about the accuracy. I was thinking about it from a different perspective. I wanted to find a way of being able to do == on the double before and after that would guarentee whatever I send in comes back out the same. I am fine with formatting the code by rounding, but no matter what i tried, the results came out skewed. I feel String conversion might just be the best route for this kind of thing.